# How to post wall in facebook using API in PHP?

Tags: facebook

I want to post score in wall in facebook using facebook API.

Comment: Can you perhaps say where you're stuck.  The docs are pretty straight forward http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have the Facebook SDK
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Initiate Facebook API

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
  'secret' => YOU_APP_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
));
```

Make sure your user has the "publish_stream" extended permission
then make a call to the facebook graph feed:

```
            $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
                'message' => "Hi",
                'link'    => 'http://mywebsite.com',
                'picture' => 'http://mywebsite.com/picture.jpg',
                'name'    => 'MyWebSite',
                'description'=> 'MyWebSite is a website for me!'
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have an access token for the user you will just need to do a POST request to the Graph API. You can read the documentation here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

The example from that page shows how to do it with php.

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Check out this funny article' \
     -F 'link=http://www.example.com/article.html' \
     -F 'picture=http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg' \
     -F 'name=Article Title' \
     -F 'caption=Caption for the link' \
     -F 'description=Longer description of the link' \
     -F 'actions={"name": "View on Zombo", "link": "http://www.zombo.com"} \
     -F 'privacy={"value": "ALL_FRIENDS"} \
     https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post something on the user's wall using the javascript API also.

These are the steps:

1. Include the facebook javascript library

   ```
   <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
   ```
2. Add facebook javascript initialization code (add this after the opening body tag)

   ```
   <div id="fb-root">
   <script type="text/javascript">
   FB.init({
         appId      : 'APP_ID', // App ID
         status     : true, // check login status
         cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
       });
       </script>
   ```
3. Call FB.UI to open the sharing popup.

   ```
   function postToFeed_one() {
             // calling the API ...
                 var obj = {
                 method: 'feed',
                 link: 'LINK_URL',
                 name: 'TITLE OF SHARED POST',
                caption: 'CAPTION FOR SHARED CONTENT',
                 description: 'DESCRIPTION FOR SHARED CONTENT'
       };
       FB.ui(obj, callback_one);
     } 
     function callback_one()
     {}
   ```
4. Call postToFeed_one() with necessary data to open the FB sharing popup.