# facebook graph api how to post page wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i little speak english

i want create feed (post, note, link) to **page wall** ANY TIME (like offline_access) with new graph api

What should I do for it , what permissions should

thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030701/how-to-post-wall-in-facebook-using-api-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create facebook app
2. take appid
3. copy this link to browser

   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=appid&redirect_uri=canvasurl&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token

provide appid and the url u given in canvas url(eg:http://localhost/web)

1. redirected url u can see access token.take that access token value.
2. Facebook_Graph_Toolkit.GraphApi.Api x = new Facebook_Graph_Toolkit.GraphApi.Api(accesstoken);

   ```
       string id = x.PostFeedToTarget("pageid", "hi test");
   ```