# How to post to my facebook wall from my own adminpages(CMS)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

How can I post a ordinary post to my facebook wall from my administration pages where I upload content to my webpage?

So I upload content to my webpage from my CMS and next to where I display my uploaded content in my adminpages I would like to have a button that can publish that post to my facebook wall. As an ordinary post and not like a LIKE post or Comment post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create an facebook app.
Then you will get an app id and a secret key.

Using this details you can do post into ur wall using facebook php library
or u can use the following function

```
<?php


    function doWallPost($postName='',$postMessage='',$postLink='',$postCaption='',$postDescription='')
    {
    $FB_APP_ID='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $FB_APP_SECRET='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    $APP_RETURN_URL=((substr($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],0,4)=="HTTP")?"http://":"https://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    if(empty($code)) 
    {
        $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$FB_APP_ID."&redirect_uri=".$APP_RETURN_URL."&scope=publish_stream";                  
        header("Location:$dialog_url");
    }

    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$FB_APP_ID."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($APP_RETURN_URL)."&client_secret=".$FB_APP_SECRET."&code=".$code;
    $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

    $param1=explode("&",$access_token);
    $param2=explode("=",$param1[0]);
    $FB_ACCESS_TOKEN=$param2[1];


    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed";
    $attachment =  array(   'access_token'  => $FB_ACCESS_TOKEN,                        
                    'name'          => $postName,
                    'link'          => $postLink,
                    'description'   => $postDescription,
                    'message'       => $postMessage,
                    'caption'       => $postCaption,
                );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    header('Content-type:text/html');
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result
    }







    ?>
```

For details
follow [How to post wall in facebook using API in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030701/how-to-post-wall-in-facebook-using-api-in-php)

Comment: Thanks a lot Akhil
But I cant use php Im afraid on my server, is there something simular in jquery - javascript?
I see the dialog_url in the above code, is the above posting to my wall, so it look just like when I post it from within facebook?
So I can post big images etc?
I dont want it to post like a comment, not like this example:http://demo.lookmywebpage.com/publish-on-facebook-wall/

I just want to be sure before I start :-)
Thanks again!

Comment: Just try one demo with this , posting something into ur fb wall, i hope one attempt will clear all ur doubts

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, but this is php code, isnt it? And my server dont support php.
And Im not sure if I understand it, if I want to get the postmessage and the other values from my database, where do I put it? And I also want to send an image at the same time, how do I do that?
Sorry :-)

Comment: Ok, now I have managed to post to my wall!
But the image that I post is small, and just like when you use the LIKE or Comment dialog.
How can I make the image big so it displays the hole width in the timeline?
Now I use this code: see below!

Answer (score 0):

> function postonwall(){
>                  // showLoader(true);
>
> ```
>             FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', 
>                 { 
>                     message     : "testtext.",
>                     link        : 'http://www.mydomain.se',
>                     picture     : 'http://www.mydomain.se/image.jpg',
>                     name        : 'iOS Apps & Games',
>                     description : 'Checkout iOS apps and games from iThinkdiff.net. I found some of them are just awesome!'
>
>             }, 
>             function(response) {
>                // showLoader(false);
>
>                 if (!response || response.error) {
>                     alert('Error occured');
>                 } else {
>                     //alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
>                   alert('Success: Content Published');
>                 }
>             });
>         }
> ```