# Remotely Posting to Facebook Page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-php-sdk

A client website has a promotional offer that updates the percentage rate on a coupon at pre-determined intervals. Each time this job runs they want the new discount percentage rate to be posted on their Facebook page.

I've read through some tutorials and documentation and I know that I have to create and application and have it request access. These updates, however, are run through cron jobs and the client only runs the promotions a few times a year. Since the offline_access permission has been deprecated, how would I handle situations where the access token has expired? I need this to be as automated as possible so that the client can manage this pretty much on their own through their Magento store front.

The replacement for offline_access, the longer lasting authorization tokens, are supposed to update each time you visit the application but considering I have no browser based client performing these actions I'm not sure how or if it would recognize anything other than the token.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Little-known fact:  If you get the `publish_stream` extended permission then you can post on a user's behalf using your application's access token rather than the user's access token.  This works in scenarios such as cron jobs.

In this scenario the `offline_access` extended permission is not required and the user's access token does not even get used.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the first paragraph of your requirements, it seems all thats needed is the ability for a post to appear on the wall of a page. To automate this you can do this using the API. The answer to the following question will brought more insight and does not seem you need any offline access for this.

[How to post wall in facebook using API in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030701/how-to-post-wall-in-facebook-using-api-in-php)

Let me know if this satisfies or if more is needed on this.